# Receiving Stripe Webhooks on a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, stripe-connect

I have a wordpress website hosted on GoDaddy.

I am an advanced stripe user and have integrated stripe with many Ruby on Rails apps , along with stripe-webhook integration with the Rails. Also i am well versed in how web-hooks work.
But recently i was made owner of a wordpress website hosted on GoDaddy and on that website i am supposed to receive stripe payment failed webhook and then trigger an email based on that webhook event.
I am not able to make much connect with wordpress and stripe from online resources and need help on how to receive stripe-webhooks in wordpress website i.e where to put code to make that happen etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same problem and pippins stripe integration plugin seemed to answer it but it had a lot of extra code I did not need so I removed it and made a concise version just for the webhook integration: [WPStripeWebhook](https://github.com/amratab/WPStripeWebhook). README is self explanatory. Basically make changes to includes/stripe_listener.php for your events. Also attaching readme here as per stackoverflow guidelines:

**Usage:**

1. Copy the complete folder WPStripeWebhook in wp-content/plugins. Go
   to website admin page.
2. Activate the WP Stripe webhook plugin for
   plugins section.
3. After this Settings will start showing Stripe
   webhook settings section. Click on it. In the page fill the stripe
   keys and check test mode option if you want to test the plugin.
4. In WPStripeWebhook/includes/stripe_listener.php, make changes for your
   event type and email or whatever you want to do in response to
   an event. It currently sends out an email.

**Important notes and suggestions**
For live mode, add stripe webhook endpoint (stripe account -> settings -> account settings -> webhook) like this

> https://yourdomain.com?webhook-listener=stripe

For testing locally on your machine, you can use Ultrahook. Its awesome! Set up your keys and username and start ultrahook on your machine using:

> ultrahook -k your_ultrahook_key stripe 8888

Add a webhook endpoint url in your stripe account similar to this:

> http://stripe.your_ultrahook_username.ultrahook.com/your_wp_website_folder_name/stripe-listener.php?webhook-listener=stripe

And it should start working for you. Also, you might see 404 in ultrahook console. Just ignore it. I would suggest setting up debugging too. It really helps. For debugging, add these to your wp_config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true); 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); 
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 ); 
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

After this, you should see a debug.log file in your wp-content folder and it will display errors and warnings and whatever you print using error_log()

Comment: Any plans to update this for the latest version of Stripe? This was looking very useful but it doesn't work and there have been big changes to stripe-php since.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents. For posterity and because the accepted answer didn't do it for me.

We can use the [WordPress REST api](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

By [Extending the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/) and [Adding Custom Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) through the [`register_rest_route` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/).

```
<?php

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wpso40015091' );

function wpso40015091() {

    $routes = array(
        array(
            'namespace' => 'wpso40015091/listener/v1',
            'route' => 'endpoint',

            //www.example.com/index.php/wp-json/wpso40015091/listener/v1/endpoint
            //This is the endpoint to add in your Stripe dashboard webhook section.
            //From time to time, depending on your host, the "index.php" might be omitted.
            //You can use "get_rest_url()" to Retrieves the URL to a REST endpoint on a site.
            //https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/
           

            'args' => array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => function () {

                    //...

                },
                'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
            ),
            'override' => true,
        ),
    );

    foreach ( $routes as $route ) {

        register_rest_route( $route['namespace'], $route['route'], $route['args'], $route['override'] );

    };

};
```

The callback function is the event listener. Stripe has a built in generator, refer https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart.